# Flutter: Some emoji display incorrectly on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, emoji

In my Flutter project, I use this function for displaying emoji

```
String unicodeToString(String unified) {
  return String.fromCharCodes(unified.split('-').map((e) {
    return int.parse(e, radix: 16);
  }));
}
```

Then, if I call it with a list of Unicode codepoints, it should spit out an emoji character.

Now, in my database (a big JSON), there are several emoji I just can't get displayed correctly on iOS.

Specifically there seems to be some issues with kiss and couple with heart emoji.

- 1F469-200D-2764-FE0F-200D-1F48B-200D-1F468 (Kiss woman man)
- 1F468-200D-2764-FE0F-200D-1F48B-200D-1F468 (Kiss man man)
- 1F469-200D-2764-FE0F-200D-1F48B-200D-1F469 (Kiss woman woman)
- 1F469-200D-2764-FE0F-200D-1F468 (Couple with heart woman man)
- 1F468-200D-2764-FE0F-200D-1F468 (Couple with heart man man)
- 1F469-200D-2764-FE0F-200D-1F469 (Couple with heart woman woman)

If I plug the one to the mentioned function,

```
unicodeToString('1F469-200D-2764-FE0F-200D-1F48B-200D-1F469')
```

it displays like that on iOS.

[image: emoji kiss woman woman]

If I use software keyboard, search for that specific emoji and type it, same issue appears.

Codepen:

https://codepen.io/johnnycook-the-bashful/pen/WNOOvOd

Flutter 2.2.2,
iOS 14.5

Comment: My suspicion is your display logic. How are you putting this on the screen? Are you further parsing the returned string in any way? These are double-ZWJ expressions, and it's possible that you have a parser that doesn't understand that. (It's possible that parser is in Flutter; I don't know Flutter, but I do know iOS and Unicode). If it's related to multiple ZWJ, then family emoji might also have trouble. You should test 1F469-200D-1F469-200D-1F467-200D-1F466. It should display ‍‍‍.

Comment: I think the used logic is working properly. It just converts the string to a list of integers and displays char from that. The issue also happens if I simply use the iOS software emoji keyboard and put the char there without any custom logic. Curiously, all the 'family' emoji work.

Comment: BTW, pasting ‍❤️‍‍ in Visual Studio Code breaks up the same way (which is in Electron; though it works in Slack which is also Electron). It does not when you paste into Xcode or SublimeText). As you suggest, this has nothing to do with unicodeToString; the same thing occurs if you replace that with the emoji itself as a string in your codepen code. It's clearly an issue in Flutter itself. (If you search for ZWJ in the Flutter issues list, you'll see they've had lots of problems over the years.)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the suggestion. For now, I just removed those six emoji from db.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code on codepen, everything is perfect.

That simply means IOS operating system doesn't support that Unicode.
No workaround for now, but below is an alternative solution.

Use the flutter emoji picker on the pub, it supports both Android and IOS.
That is the Material design and Cupertino

https://pub.dev/packages/emoji_picker_flutter

Comment: Why do you believe iOS doesn't support this emoji? It's available in the keyboard (and my tests with SwiftUI display these without trouble). I don't know anything about how Flutter handles ZWJ emojis, but there's no reason to believe this is an OS issue.

Comment: No, iOS supports that emoji. It even displays it correctly in different apps. I already tried the mentioned emoji_picker_flutter and other packages. Same issue everywhere. My guess is Flutter itself causes the issue. And yes, on Android and web it works ok.